# Java base In-Memory caching solution with bulk loading and eviction policy

Tags: java, caching, guava, ehcache

Looking for in-memory standalone caching solution for the below use-case.

Database tables stores

- Details of SalesPerson and SalesArea
- Hourly area-wise sale details

Wanted to cache SalesPerson and SalesArea details, which are technically static during 8 hours sales shift. So as to avoid querying database on consolidating hourly sales.

Guava Cache is my first choice which supports eviction policy. I can set to 8hours to refresh cache entries. Unfortunately it doesn't supports loading cache entries in bulk, instead one-by-one on demand.

Ref: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=775

Any thoughts on alternate solutions much appreciable

Comment: So what is wrong with CacheLoader.loadAll?

Comment: That issue talks about "when we release version 11" - looks like public guava is up to version 19, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the javadoc of [`CacheLoader.loadAll`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html#loadAll(java.lang.Iterable)):

> This method should be overriden when bulk retrieval is significantly more efficient than many individual lookups

This sounds very much like what you're describing.